# How to render clean Symfony JsonResponse in twig using Ajax?

Tags: json, ajax, symfony, symfony4

I'm making search feature in Symfony4 using JavaScript ,but when I render using Ajax the result is kinda not clean. It prints with other character.

I'm getting like following on the results..

result.html.twig

```
{ "res": "

       1    Mousepad    30  50  40  \n edit | \n delete\n 

\n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n " }
```

Symfony

```
    return new JsonResponse([
        'res' => $this-> renderView('admin/product_results.html.twig',[ 'item' => $item ])
    ]);
```

Ajax after success:

> document.getElementById("d").innerHTML =
>   JSON.stringify(data,null,'\t');

As you can see in above I'm getting

> { "res": "

and

> \n \n

So how do I get the result without those characters?

Comment: so, the value you get from your api is json, and on the supposed object you get as return, you call `JSON.stringify` to turn it into json, but you want a string for innerHTML ... I'm very confused. have you tried `.innerHTML = data.res;` ? (side-note: `\n` is a line break encoded in json, so if you don't re-encode it, it should just be a line break.

Comment: Using twig to generate json can be challenging.  Just use a [serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html).

Answer (score 0):

You do better not use Twig to send a JSON response. Instead build an array in your controller and use symfony's JSONResponse class to convert your array to JSON and send the response without using Twig. Here is an example

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class DefaultController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/sample", name="app_sample")
     */
    public function buidSampleData()
    {
        $data = [
            'result' => 'success',
            'users' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'Frank',
                    'age' => 32
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'Ozzy',
                    'age' => 28
                ]
            ]
        ];

        return new JsonResponse($data);
    }
}
```

[See the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#creating-a-json-response)